# Varnish book: Connection failed (localhost:1234): (null)

Tags: varnish

**Ubuntu 16.04**

**varnishd (varnish-4.1.8 revision d266ac5c6)**

I'm reading The Varnish book.

I did this exercise:
http://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/Getting_Started.html#exercise-configure-varnish

Namely: "See Table 2 and locate the Varnish configuration file for your installation. Open and edit that file to listen to client requests on port 80 and have the management interface on port 1234".

Now I have:

**varnish**

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:1234 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

**default.vcl**

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

Then to the best of my ability I did what was necessary in Exercise: Configure Varnish.

At least, I have restarted:

```
service varnish restart
```

And I came to the next exercise: 
http://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/Getting_Started.html#vcl-reload

```
$ sudo service varnish reload
Job for varnish.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status varnish.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


$ systemctl status varnish.service
● varnish.service - Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) (Result: exit-code) since Пт 2017-09-15 16:31:56 MSK; 12min ago
  Process: 20980 ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/reload-vcl (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 20089 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /
 Main PID: 20114 (varnishd)
    Tasks: 218
   Memory: 129.6M
      CPU: 614ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/varnish.service
           ├─20114 /usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varn
           └─20117 /usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varn

сен 15 16:33:05 michael-desktop systemd[1]: Reloading Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator.
сен 15 16:33:05 michael-desktop reload-vcl[20389]: Connection failed (localhost:1234): (null)
сен 15 16:33:05 michael-desktop reload-vcl[20389]: Error: vcl.load vcl_b5ad5589-cf76-4f2b-b14d-734d35b13e
сен 15 16:33:05 michael-desktop systemd[1]: varnish.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
сен 15 16:33:05 michael-desktop systemd[1]: Reload failed for Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP acce
сен 15 16:43:55 michael-desktop systemd[1]: Reloading Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator.
сен 15 16:43:55 michael-desktop reload-vcl[20980]: Connection failed (localhost:1234): (null)
сен 15 16:43:55 michael-desktop reload-vcl[20980]: Error: vcl.load vcl_38fbe034-b800-4315-af87-c90bf6fe3a
сен 15 16:43:55 michael-desktop systemd[1]: varnish.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
сен 15 16:43:55 michael-desktop systemd[1]: Reload failed for Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP acce
lines 1-23/23 (END)
```

Well, **Connection failed (localhost:1234): (null)** 
But I seem to have followed the book.

When I try manually:

```
$ varnishadm -T localhost:1234
Connection failed (localhost:1234): (null)
```

I checked whether the port is occupied: netstat -nlpt

The port is free.

Could you give me a kick here.

Comment: What happens if you try to manually start `varnishd` using the modified `default.vcl`?  I.e., rather than reloading, stop varnish and then run `varnishd -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl`? If there are errors in the vcl you should see that on the console.

Comment: Does your question contain the *entire contents* of your `default.vcl` file?

Comment: I stopped varnish: sudo service varnish stop. Then: sudo varnishd -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
Error: Cannot open socket: :80: Address already in use
But it is Apache that occupies 80.

Comment: As for whether tis is the entire default.vcl. No. But the content of other directives is commented out.

Comment: Only one service can bind to a port. If Apache is bound to port 80 then Varnish will fail.  From the examples it looks like the assumption is that Apache is listening on port 8080. Maybe you just need to fix the `Listen` directives in your Apache configuration?

Comment: I was wrong. It is not Apache that is listening at 80. It is Varnish. I stopped Apache and saw Varnish's angry message. Apache is listening at 8080.

Comment: Solved. My Ubuntu is systemd, whereas I adjusted config file for SysV. But thank you anyway.